# Multiple aggregates in SPARQL

Tags: aggregate-functions, sparql

I have a triple store that contains mail archive data. So let's say I have a lot of persons (`foaf:Person`) that have sent (`ex:hasSent`) and received (`ex:hasReceived`) emails (`ex:Email`).

Example:

```
SELECT ?person ?email
WHERE {
    ?email  rdf:type   ex:Email.
    ?person rdf:type   foaf:Person;
            ex:hasSent ?email.
}
```

The same works for `ex:hasReceived`, of course. Now I would like to do some statistics and analytics, i.e. determine how many emails an individual has sent and received. Doing this for only one predicate is a simple aggregation:

```
SELECT ?person (COUNT(?email) AS ?count)
WHERE {
    ?email  rdf:type   ex:Email.
    ?person rdf:type   foaf:Person;
            ex:hasSent ?email.
}
GROUP BY ?person
```

However, I need need the number of received emails as well and I would like to do this without having to issue a separate query. So I tried the following:

```
SELECT ?person (COUNT(?email1) AS ?sent_emails) (COUNT(?email2) AS ?received_emails)
WHERE {
  ?person rdf:type foaf:Person.

  ?sent_email rdf:type ex:Email.
  ?person ex:hasSent ?sent_email.

  ?received_email rdf:type ex:Email.
  ?person ex:hasReceived ?received_email.
}
GROUP BY ?person
```

This did not seem to be right, as the numbers for the emails sent vs. received were exactly the same. I assume this is because my SPARQL statement results in a cross product of all mails a person has ever sent and received, right?

What do I need to do in order to get the statistics right on a per-individual basis?

Comment: You could also avoid the cross-product by wrapping your statements with `{...} UNION {...}`. You will get the same amount of rows but you will have null entries in opposing columns. Hmm, this is perhaps more useful if you use `SUM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT(?email1)` isn't counting anything as `?email1` is undefined.  Also, there is partial cross product as you mention - `DISTINCT` will help.

Try `(COUNT(DISTINCT ?sent_email) AS ?sent_emails)`

Comment: You are right, `?email1` was unbound. I had polished the query for SO, but not fully.